# Hows paintComponent linked to the user defined class?

Tags: java

I am new to java but not new to Programming and i am not able to understand hows `paintComponent(Graphics graphics)`, `mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)` and `mouseMoved(MouseEvent event)` gets linked to the `public static void main(String[] args)` method. Please help me understand this issue.

```
package com.company;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Leaning Java");
        HelloComponent helloObject = new HelloComponent("Ajay");
        frame.add(helloObject);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class HelloComponent extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener {
    String theMessage;
    int messageX = 125, messageY = 95;

    public HelloComponent(String string) {
        theMessage = string;
        addMouseMotionListener(this);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        graphics.drawString(theMessage, messageX, messageY);
    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        messageX = event.getX();
        messageY = event.getY();
        repaint();
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing more that you need to do in your code to call those methods.

`paintComponent` is called by the parent of the `JComponent`. In your case, you're adding an instance of `HelloComponent` to a `JFrame`. The `JFrame` will call `paintComponent` when necessary.

`mouseDragged` and `mouseMoved` are methods defined in the `MouseMotionListener` interface. By calling `addMouseMotionListener(this)`, you register your class to receive those messages when the appropriate mouse actions happen.

Comment: Ok, but `paintComponent` is overridden but its not called anywhere. Creating object of the class `HelloComponent` automatically calls `paintComponent` or what. if thats the reason, then y its not implemented inside `constructor`.

Comment: The overridden method is still called by the parent component (your JFrame). You add `helloObject` to the `frame`. `frame` knows that it can call `paintComponent` on all components that have been added to it. If you override `paintComponent`, it will still be called by `frame` - but now, it's the `paintComponent` that *you* defined, not the one that originally came with JComponent, that will be called.